How to increase the spindown time on idle for an external hard drive (HDD) in Windows 11?
Windows 11 is spinning down external hard drives (HDDs) just seconds after they are used.  This is resulting low access times, and possible increased chance of data loss due to heads repeatedly getting parked over and over again.  As such, I would like to increase the amount of time Windows 11 waits until spinning down external HDDs that it thinks are idle.  I've found many "answers" online, but they affect all drives, including internal drives.  I don't want changes to affect internal drives; I only want to control external hard drives.
I did find this unanswered old Super User question, but it doesn't mention Windows, and I'm interested in a Windows-specific answer, as Linux and macOS do not have the same problem with the same drives.
If it matters, the HDD drives are made by Western Digital (WD).

Would you be satisfied with a third-party tool?

@security_paranoid Yes. Not my first choice, but definitely yes (especially if it's open source)! Thanks.

Not sure if it could do specifically what you want, but WD do have their own private disk utils. I think they’re free and might be worth a try. I’ve also heard that CrystalDiskInfo is good, but sadly not free, I think.

does this answered old super user question help?
